# How to complain effectively / warn others about company which arranges online interview, and the recruiter doesn't even show up - twice?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, unprofessional-behavior

Acknowledging that this is not strictly "workplace", I'm looking for a way to warn others and make the company under question feel some little social pressure. You may say I'm looking for a tripadvisor-type place for reviews of bad interviewing experiences.

To give some detail, following an application by me a recruiter asked me to arrange for an initial interview. I was in front of my computer at the appointed time, but absolutely nothing happened; after a few minutes I wrote an email, still nothing.

After the arranged time slot was over I received an automated email with a time change to the next day. I was there, again nothing happened, again no communication or explanation.

This has severely disrupted my work schedule for this week. I'd like to warn others against this, and if possible also hear about tactics to protect oneself against such cases.

Comment: Glassdoor has a section for interview reviews

Comment: @SmallChess thank you! Due to your impolite and off-the-mark comment I browsed through your other replies to others (many of them on the same style ... geez, what do you perceive yourself as being?). And by reading other people's, more useful, replies, I came to remember about Glassdoor! That's where it seems like I can warn others. Sir, I wish you all your future pro interactions to go exactly like the one that you didn't think I should warn others about :)

Comment: @JoeStevens thanks - I found out and was writing simultaneously with you about this. If you want to turn this into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it's asking for a resource recommendation.

Comment: @dukeling however it serves a purpose very related to navigating job search.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: As a general rule on SE network, asking for external resources (tutorial, sites,...) is generally considered as off topic and opinion biaised. This is why such question are closed. If your question were about escalating the problem to the manager of HR, it would be on topic (though the answers may just advise may to move on instead of losing energy and time).

Comment: Thanks for the pointing out of the rules, I didn't know it. (Although I will admit that I don't see why it is considered wrong since it is not a tutorial but a site with a very specific objective, and learning about Glassdoor has already helped me). On the other hand, I'll disagree with your advice of moving on: one should never choose preserving energy and time fixing unprofessional and potentially disrupting to others behaviour over doing nothing. Not to mention letting people get away with whatever they can get away with.

Comment: Lol... I tried to interview at [Space X](https://www.spacex.com/) three times with one recruiter. He missed every scheduled call (I even left it up to him to pick the date and time). I finally gave up and began tagging his email to me as spam. (It was a contractor that helps with hiring; not the company's HR department).

Comment: @jww :0 (Eventually I got to chat after I reached out on Twitter. In the meantime I'd also used Glassdoor btw.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glassdoor.com has a section for interview reviews (as Joe Stevens pointed out).

Edit: Just adding, as was mentioned in the comments above, that reaching out to the company's Twitter helped with complaining (and arranging an actual interview). About the warning others part, see first half of this answer.

Comment: Welcome aboard, Helen. It is acceptable, indeed, welcome, to accept your own answer (although the system may make you wait before doing so), as this will help others in future.

Comment: @mawg thank you a lot! However, seeing that this question has (unexpectedly and surprisingly) attracted controversy, I'll avoid doing so. Btw and also judging from other questions, it seems like "too broad" is the new dislike button :)

Comment: Alas, I am out of votes already, or I would upvote your comment. Welcome to the wonderful community that is SE ;-/  I still think that you should accept your own answer, especially as there won't be any others, now that the question is, regrettably, on hold

Comment: @mawg thanks again! I've been (a little) more active on other SE forums so I know the level of greatness it can reach xD I must confess though that forums focusing on interpersonal advice tend to attract very varied answers and reactions...